# VS 2015 Indent Guides for Javascript files?

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering if I can get indent guides on VS 2015 for **Javascript** files? I have seen the Indent Guides extension but was unsure if it would work for Javascript files.

Comment: you should search more first before ask something here...

Comment: @Filip - I mean, I get what you're saying but no where in the documentation of Indent Guides does it state what types of files it actually works on. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveDowerMSFT.IndentGuides#overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the [Indent Guides extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveDowerMSFT.IndentGuides) and it does work for Javascript files!